# NSURLConnection validation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to validate weather the connection was successful but have been getting inconstant results. When I try to do an synchronous request using a bogus url with:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (responseData)   
    {  
        did_send = TRUE;  
    }   
    else   
    {  
        did_send = FALSE;
    }
```

It hangs for a while an eventually returns:

```
 did_send = FALSE;
```

But if I do an asynchronous request using a bogus url with:

```
NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self ];
if (conn)   
    {  
        did_send = TRUE;  
    }   
    else   
    {  
        did_send = FALSE;
    }
```

I get:

```
did_send = TRUE;
```

every time. I need to get the asynchronous request working because I am able to set a timeout and not have to hang for 60 sec while the request times out with the default time out duration that is unchangeable with the asynchronous requests. Any ideas?

Comment: Its not really an answer, but for asynchronous request i found using ASIHTTPRequest to be much easier/understandable than the apple apis themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the nsurlconnection class delegate method [connection:didFailWithError:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJGFGCF)  This should give you consistent results.

```
-(void)getLocationsFromWebService {
    NSLog(@"in getLocationsFromWebService");


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:TRUE];


    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.locationsURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:100.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    self.requestType = @"GET";
    if (theConnection) {
        _responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain ];
    } else {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE];
    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE]; 
    NSLog(@"in mapviewcontroller");
    NSLog(@"Error connecting - %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    [connection release];
    [_responseData release];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSInteger statusCode = [HTTPResponse statusCode];

    if (404 == statusCode || 500 == statusCode) {
        //[self.controller setTitle:@"Error Getting Parking Spot ....."];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE];

        [connection cancel];
        NSLog(@"Server Error - %@", [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:statusCode]);
    } else {
        if ([self.requestType isEqualToString:@"GET"])
            [_responseData setLength:0];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if ([self.requestType isEqualToString:@"GET"])
        [_responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    if ([self.requestType isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
        [self parseLocations:_responseData];
        [_responseData release];
    }
    [connection release];

}
```

Comment: could you provide some examples as to how to use this method to solve my problem?

Comment: I;ve added some of my own code to my answer.  Please feel free to use it anyway you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply instantiating `NSURLConnection` does nothing. It creates an instance of that class but does not begin the data transfer--the object will generally be non-nil even if the request is impossible to satisfy.

Rather, your delegate object (`self` in your code) needs to implement `NSURLConnectionDelegate` (which will handle callbacks such as "incoming data" or "error condition.") Then you must send the `NSURLConnection` instance the `-start` message, which will schedule it on the executing thread's run loop.

For more information on the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol (including information on what to do in your callbacks), see Apple's "[URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)."